# How to keep looping an function in another class and pass return value to another class

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

Suppose I am having a function to return ping response time to my server address.

```
public class Ping{
public static Long ping(String host) {
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            if (address.isReachable(1000)) {
                return Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMillis();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Host not available, nothing to do here
        }
        return Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis();
    
}}
```

And another class that create a **server** object to store all required value("localhost" as example).

```
serverStatus.setConnectivity(Ping.ping("localhost").doubleValue());
```

Will I be able to keep looping the ping function inside Ping class and pass the return result to the serverStatus setter which is in another class **StatusMapper**. Or looping the ping function inside StatusMapper class like below

```
double ping = 0;
while true{
ping = Ping.ping("localhost").doubleValue();
}
serverStatus.setConnectivity(ping);
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a rather broad solution space here - as you can imagine there are many ways to do what you are describing here.

The way that I would approach this is to create a functional interface that can accept ping durations. Then pass a lamba of that into your ping function. Such that it calls back into whatever class you need it to.

Your code would look like something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

@FunctionalInterface
interface DurationAcceptor
{
    void acceptPing(Long l);
}

class Server implements DurationAcceptor
{
    private volatile Long serverStatus;

    @Override public void acceptPing(Long l)
    {
        serverStatus = l;
    }
}

public class Ping
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        while(true)
        {
            Ping.ping("localhost", server::acceptPing);
        }
    }

    public static void ping(String host, DurationAcceptor acceptor)
    {
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            if (address.isReachable(1000))
            {
                acceptor.acceptPing(Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMillis());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Host not available, nothing to do here
        }
        acceptor.acceptPing(Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis());
    }
}
```